# How to host Flutter on the web using Firebase? And how well does it work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web, hosting

How do I host flutter on the web using firebase and how well does it work? I have never done this before but have used firebase to host html, javascript and Css pages in the past. I am now learning flutter and dart for mobile and web development. I was looking for methods on how to host flutter using firebase and how well it works. Thanks!

Comment: on running flutter build web, copy the files in the build/web directory and paste in your public, then run firebase deploy, for a pwa its alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building it, a Flutter web app is just some HTML + JavaScript. This means that you can host it on any static web host, including Firebase Hosting. Just deploy the output of your build process (from `build/web`) to Firebase, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

verify if the path used by the command `firebase init` is okay. Its under this line :

> You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

if not, follow the directory and delete build and .firebase folders and the file firebase.json. After that, run the `firebase unit`, `flutter build web` and `firebase deploy --only hosting`. Be sure too delete the cache of your browser after that.

Have an nice day

source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJo7Mqse960&t=305s